# Action Script - how to go to another scene from movieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to go to another scene by clicking a button witch is placed in a mc and I got an error.
This is my code below

```
Play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gotoScene2); 
function gotoScene2(evt:MouseEvent){
    movClip.gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 2");
}
```

(this code is placed inside a movieClip witch is instantiated like "movClip", at frame 260 - may be this help to understand better).
And this is the erorr i get: 
Symbol 'preloader26',Layer'Layer9',Frame 260,Line 4 1120:Access of undefined property movClip
I hope anyone can help me...thanks very much!

Comment: `Play_btn` is placed inside of `movClip` ?

Comment: yes is inside at frame 260

Comment: did you tried this: `this.gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 2");`

Comment: when i put 'this', i receive the bellow erorr: ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene 2 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at Exotic_fla::preloader26_2/gotoScene2()

Comment: i think, 'this' means eventlistener not movieClip in this case... isn't?

Comment: ok , so try this: `MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 2");`

Comment: `this` means object that creates an `EventListener`

Comment: Thank you man , you are a legend!..... i didn't sleep 4 hours yesterday because of this... how can i make this good answer? for incress your reputation on forum? (I'm new here) Thanks again!!!

Comment: Great , glad it works. I've posted it like answer , so you can "accept" this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get the parent of the object , like this:

```
MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 2");
```