# Animate Actionscript 3.0 scene not found, but scene exists

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, jquery-animate, adobe, adobe-animate

My project is an interactive ebook and I created different scenes for each page ( there are 1 to 19 scenes)
I need to insert some ActionScript in order to be able to return to the homepage, and go to some other pages but when I click in the button in the scene, this error keeps showing up :

> ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene 1 was not found.
>   at
>   flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
>     at
>   OPP_TCC_fla::MainTimeline/fl_ClickToGoToScene_50()

The code that I have written is :

```
 b_home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToScene_50);

function fl_ClickToGoToScene_50(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1");
}
```

[image]

I don't know how to fix that! Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Probably **...gotoAndPlay(1, "Cena 19");** ?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that doesn't always work either...

> ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene ElDiabloChase was not found.
>   at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
>   at Final_Project_v13b_QuitCode__700X438__EndCredits_fla::MainTimeline/ClickToGoToScene1()[Final_Project

I've literally stooped to the ridiculous task of copying the name from the scene list and pasting it into the code.

If you test the movie in a browser, it'll work most of the time, but in Animate, I can almost never get it to work right.

All I can think is that it's a weird "**# of character thing**" or something like that. I'm stumped.

[Scene List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLREV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Like @Organis said in the comment, you have to specify the scene in the second argument.

`MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Cena 19");` is going to take you to the first frame of `Cena 19`.

`MovieClip(this.root).gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1");` is going to take you to the first frame of `Scene 1`.

See the answer to this question: [Action Script - how to go to another scene from movieClip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997398/action-script-how-to-go-to-another-scene-from-movieclip)